# getting url of the file making post call to a php

Tags: php

I am creating a service where I give out some data from my database to other websites. I scrap data off websites store them into a proper format perform some calculations on them and then sell that data to users to use in their websites.

Now I created a script in which I provide a unique id to my users and they they send that id with the POST data to verify themselves. But here the security issue is that these ids can be distributed to several people and they all can use the same id to query my data.

What I was thinking if there was a way by which I can get the url of the file which makes the POST call. This url and id combination then can be used to provide unauthorised access.

I used $_SERVER in my scripts but it provides IP address of remote calling file...Is there any method by which I can get the url or the hostname of the caling file??

Regards

Comment: It would be the `REFERER` but you should **not** rely on that as it can be forged easily.

Comment: Yeah I know it can be forged easily thats why I am not using that...also many times the REFERRER field is just empty and hence its not very reliable to use...Is there any other method which I can use for the same???

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].  Do note, however, that you should have error trapping set up for this, as it can be blank.  Also note that this can be fairly easily spoofed, so if you care about accuracy, don't count on this.

However, it *is* the referring domain.